# Unable to add and delete any service in Ambari 2.5.2.1

Tags: azure, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I am trying to add service in Ambari 2.5.2.1 on HDInsight 3.6 cluster (HDP 2.6 is used there), but there is no "Add Service" button in "Actions" drop down menu and the ones from Admin/Stack_and_Versions menu don't work at all. There aren't also "Delete" buttons for installed services.

I should mention, that I'm logged in as admin user. This problem occures only in Ambari 2.5.2.1, everything was perfectly good when I used earlier version of HDInsight and Ambari, but unfortunately I should use HDInsight 3.6

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is pretty simple - it's now impossible to add services to your cluster using Ambari if you use HDInsight. Script Action should be used for that

Comment: Do you have any link / doc which explains this need for script task?